# What features does threadsanitizer lack that are supported by helgrind, and vice-versa?

Tags: multithreading, gcc, valgrind, compiler-specific, thread-sanitizer

Performance aside, what features does gcc -fsanitize=thread lack that are supported by valgrind --tool=helgrind, and vice-versa?  Is it platform-dependent?

Which detects the most critical errors? I would like to use only one if I can, since gcc threadsanitize is incompatible with address sanitization, and valgrind makes my project run much slower.